# How to improve a LH=RH chain proof

Tags: isabelle, proof, chain

I am tying to get a better understanding how Isabelle manages the chain proofs, specifically when associativity/commutativity is involved. Imagine I have a binary non-homogeneous operator `op` that is quite complex (and it involves some set operations). Its application looks like `op(x, k)`, where k is some sort of index. Then I want to show it is associative in the sense that

`op(op(x, k), l) = op(op(x, l), k)`.

The proof starts from the LH, unfold the definition of `op`, then use associativity/commutativity of set operators, to finally arrive at RH.

My (poor) way of doing this is:

```
lemma "op(op(x, k), l) = op(op(x, l), k)"
proof - 
 have a1: "op(op(x, k), l) = LHStep1" (some rewriting) <proof>
 have a2: "LHStep1 = LHStep2" (some more rewriting) <proof>
...
 have ai+1: "LHStepi = SOMETHING" <proof>
 have ai: "SOMETHING = RHStepi" (here usually the terms are switched in the order of RH) <proof>
...
[the reverse steps to get to the actual RH]
...
 have an: "RHStep1 = RH" <proof>
 then show ?thesis using a1 a2... an by auto
qed
```

While this works, it pains me greatly to basically duplicate the proofs. Stopping in the middle so far proved to be unsuccessful. Also, most of the time using `have... moreover... ultimately` fails, hence the naming of the intermediary steps and using them all in the end, another ugly aspect.

I am not doing any calculations, this is a mathematical structure with a set of operators and axioms on which I need to prove some mathematical properties.

I am missing something and I don't know what. As usual, any help or pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The `have ... also...finally` construct should be more reliable than `have...moreover...ultimately` in this case, see for example the proof of the [binomial theorem](https://isarmathlib.org/Ring_Binomial_ZF.html#a_binomial_theorem) and the corresponding [source](https://github.com/SKolodynski/IsarMathLib/blob/caa0802e22f48aff199251ce63b726863ba7a279/IsarMathLib/Ring_Binomial_ZF.thy#L435) (note this is Isabelle/ZF, but it should work the same in Isabelle/HOL I think).